Relatively free abelian groups
I am trying to understand why $\mathbb{Z}_2 + \mathbb{Z}_4$ is not relatively free in the variety of abelian groups of period $n$. I can see that the basis set (according to the definition) should be of elements of order 4. But what's next? Moreover, why can relatively free abelian groups be of the form $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$?

Can you write down all the elements of order 4?  Does any collection of them span $\Bbb{Z}_2 + \Bbb{Z}_4$?  Same process for $\Bbb{Z}_n^k$.

What is $n$? Did you mean "abelian groups of period $4$"? And do you mean direct sum?

$A=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ does not have the universal property of relatively free groups relative to the groups of period $4$. Show that no choice of two generators $x_1$ and $x_2$ will give you a homomorphism from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ sending $x_1$ to $(1,0)$ and $x_2$ to $(0,1)$. The groups $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$ are relatively free in the variety of abelian groups of exponent $n$ because they do have the universal property.

"Why can relatively free abelian groups be of form $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$"? No, they can't; at least not the "relatively free abelian groups" (that is, the free groups in the variety of all abelian groups). Were you thinking of a proper subvariety of the variety of all abelian groups? Which one?

@ArturoMagidin I meant abelian variety of groups period $n$. Could you please elaborate on the ways of checking the universal property?

@ArturoMagidin I mean, according to the definition: for some set of generators $X$ and for any mapping $\phi$ to any group $G$ in the class $K$ there exists a single homomorhism, extending $\phi$. How can it be applied?

In the variety $\mathfrak{V}$ of all abelian groups of exponent $n$, the relatively $\mathfrak{V}$-free groups of finite rank are precisely the groups $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$.
First, they are relative $\mathfrak{V}$-groups. Written multiplicatively with generators $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. Let $G$ be any abelian group of exponent $n$. If $g_i\in G$, then there is a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_n\to g_i$ sending the generator to $g_i$. Then given $g_1,\ldots,g_k$, the set map $f\colon\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}\to G$ sending $x_i$ to $g_i$ gives a family of homomorphisms $f_i\colon\langle x_i\rangle \to G$ with $f_i(x_i)=g_i$. Then $F=f_1+\cdots+f_k\colon\mathbb{Z}_n^k\to G$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$ to $G$ extending $f$. Since $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ generate $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$, any two morphisms that agree on the $x_i$ are equal, so $F$ is unique. This proves that these groups are relatively $\mathfrak{V}$-free.
These are the only relatively $\mathfrak{V}$-groups. Let $A$ be any other group in $\mathfrak{V}$. Then we can write it in the form
$$A\cong \mathbb{Z}_{a_1}\oplus\cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{a_k}$$
with $a_1\mid a_2$, $a_2\mid a_3,\ldots, a_{k-1}\mid a_k$, and $a_k\mid n$.
By picking a prime $p$ that divides $a_1$ and considering the quotient $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^k$, we see that any generating set for $A$ must have at least $k$ elements (since this quotient is a vector space of dimension $k$). If $a_1\lt n$, then there is no surjective homomorphism from $A$ to $(\mathbb{Z}_n)^k$, so the map from a generating set $X$ of $A$ to the generators of $(\mathbb{Z}_n)^k$ cannot be extended to a group homomorphism. Thus $A$ is not relatively $\mathfrak{V}$-free when $a_1\lt n$.
For example, $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ has $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a quotient, so any generating set must have at least two elements. But if $X$ is such a set, then any map from $X$ to the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ given by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ cannot be extended to a group homomorphism, since $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ does not have $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ as a quotient. So $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ cannot be relatively free in the class of groups of exponent $4$ (or of any exponent that is a multiple of $4$, for that matter).
